# C++ MFC OO4O with Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

My oracle database contains unicode characters,but I can not use OO4O to get them(C++ MFC). Because OO4O does not support **wchar_t** type, but **only char** type.

```
oresult CODynaset::GetFieldValue(const char *fieldname, char *val, unsigned short maxlen) const
```

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Comment: So what _do_ you get using char when your database field contains a  non ASCII character? Maybe its UTF-8? Check that.

Comment: Hi @Jabberwocky, our projects written in C++ using Multibyte-Character Set. Now we convert them to Unicode Character Set. We changed the types of fields to Nvarchar and use Oracle Sql Developer to update those fields with Unicode characters without a hassle. We're using OO4O which does not support wchar_t. Some guy said that I can not use OO4O to work with unicode but I'm not sure.